# PHPJasperXML for PHP 7

Tags: php

As we already know, PHP 7 has been working in diferents plataforms now, I have been using PHPJasperXML to create different kinds of report with ireport for php, but mi reports stopped working after migrating my system to PHP 7.

Someone knows how to resolve this problem, or someone has been able to modify the phpjasperxml library for working in php 7?

Comment: Do you have any kind of error message to provide?

Comment: The only error I have got is "PHPJasperXML has a deprecated constructor", I have looked for in other forums how to resolve it, many say that I need to change de constructor like this "public __contruct()" but when I change that, the PDF created is just appear in white.

Comment: If you change the constructor of the class, make sure the places calling the constructor do it the right way `new JasperXML()`

Answer (score 0):

I have updated some of the scripts to be compatible with php7

change

```
public function PHPJasperXML($lang="en",$pdflib="TCPDF") {
    $this->lang=$lang;
    $this->setErrorReport(0);        
    $this->pdflib=$pdflib;
    if($this->fontdir=="")
    $this->fontdir=dirname(__FILE__)."/tcpdf/fonts";
}
```

on file PHP JasperXML.inc.php to

```
function __construct($lang="en",$pdflib="TCPDF") {
    $this->lang=$lang;
    $this->pdflib=$pdflib;
}
```

then change old mysql connections of

```
$this->myconn = @mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
```

to

```
$this->myconn = @mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

See 
https://github.com/PHPJasper/phpjasper
has support to PHP 7

**About**

PHPJasper is the best solution to compile and process JasperReports (.jrxml & .jasper files) just using PHP, in short: to generate reports using PHP.

**Notes:**

- PHPJasper Can be used regardless of your PHP Framework
- For PHP versions less than 7.0 see: v1.16
- Here are several examples of how to use PHPJasper